# Accessing an S3 Bucket in Account A from an EC2 Instance in Account B using a Cross-Account Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

## Introduction

- `Account-A`

  - There is an S3 bucket (`sample-s3-bucket-in-account-a`) in this account
  - This S3 bucket is configured with server-side encryption using `AWS KMS` (`SSE-KMS`)
  - The AMS KMS key is `aws/s3` (AWS managed key)
  - The bucket has **no** bucket policy
  - There is an IAM cross-account role (`sample-cross-account-role-4-s3-access-in-account-a`) created in this account

    - `Account-B` is the trusted entity (trust policy)
    - The permission policy allows the following actions on the S3 bucket (`sample-s3-bucket-in-account-a`):

      - `s3:ListBucket`
      - `s3:GetBucketLocation`
      - `s3:GetObject`
- `Account-B`

  - There is an EC2 instance in this account
  - There is also an IAM instance profile and role (`sample-iam-role-4-ec2-in-account-b`)
  - The IAM instance profile has permission to assume the cross-account role (`sample-cross-account-role-4-s3-access-in-account-a`) created in `Account-A`
  - The IAM instance profile is attached to the EC2 instance

## Given Facts

- I can generate temporary STS credentials on the EC2 instance in `Account-B` using `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT-A]:role/sample-cross-account-role-4-s3-access-in-account-a --role-session-name s3-cross-account-access-session`. Using these temporary STS credentials, I can list objects present in the S3 bucket in `Account-A`
- I can create a `profile` in the `~/.aws/config` file and use that `profile name` in aws CLI to access objects present in the S3 bucket in `Account-A` (Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/)

## Problem

- I have a `CodeDeploy` agent running on the EC2 instance
- The `CodeDeploy` agent uses `AWS SDK for Ruby`
- The `CodeDeploy` agent runs using `root` privileges
- The `CodeDeploy` agent is internally generating STS credentials using the `sample-iam-role-4-ec2-in-account-b` instance profile/role (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/sample-iam-role-4-ec2-in-account-b`)
- Unfortunately, these temporary STS credentials are not allowing `CodeDeploy` agent to download objects from the S3 bucket in `Account-A`
- There is an `Access Denied` error in the log
- I can make things work by using the S3 bucket policy but the requirement is to use a cross-account IAM role

Can anyone please tell me how I can make or configure `CodeDeploy` agent running in `Account-B` to assume `sample-cross-account-role-4-s3-access-in-account-a` instead of `sample-iam-role-4-ec2-in-account-b`?

Answer (score 0):

> I can make things work by using the S3 bucket policy but the requirement is to use a cross-account IAM role

You can't do this, unless you write your own program which will run as part of `appspec.yml`. Your program would have to "manually" assume the role and get S3 object.

Otherwise, S3 bucket policy is the only why to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift response Marcin. Too bad that the solution I am looking for is not feasible even though it is a very valid use case. Unfortunately, the revision never gets downloaded from S3 to EC2 so there is no way the CodeDeploy agent can view the appspec.yml file. Appreciate the help. CodeDeploy is also not honoring the the AWS environment variables or the ~/.aws/credentials file. It just seems to have a mind of it's own and going straight for the instance profile.

Comment: @SreenivasReddy I see. So the only option is bucket policy.